# double quote using jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl, double-quotes

I have a piece of jsp code like this:

```
<c:if test="${application.getAttribute("disableTimeoutWarning") }">
<% do something %>
</c:if>
```

I get this jsp error:

```
/jsp/header.jsp(20,61) equal symbol expected
```

I tried couple of those:

```
<c:if test='${application.getAttribute("disableTimeoutWarning") }'>
<c:if test="${application.getAttribute('disableTimeoutWarning') }">
<c:if test='${application.getAttribute('disableTimeoutWarning') }'>
```

I know I can use something like this:

```
<%
if ( application.getAttribute("disableTimeoutWarning")) {
%>
```

I want to do this using jstl core if possible. 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: The two first attempts are syntaxically correct. What happens when you use one of them? What is application? Is it the servlet context? If so, you should simply use `<c:if test="${disableTimeoutWarning}">` or `<c:if test="${applicationScope.disableTimeoutWarning}">`

Comment: @JBNizet  the application here is servletContext.

Comment: @JBNizet is correct. You can't call methods in that way with jstl - you access properties.  The `applicationScope` object will have property `disableTimeoutWarning` if it's been defined as an attribute on the servlet context.  So `<c:if test="${applicationScope.disableTimeoutWarning}">` is what you should use.

Answer (score 0):

according to the comments.this is the answer:

```
<c:if test="${applicationScope.disableTimeoutWarning}">
```